# I can't enter to "localhost:8080/phpmyadmin"

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost

Im trying to enter and it says This site can't be reached: connection refused... also, I made sure that the settings are right on the html files of the modules I am currently using which are apache and mysql. I've read through the web and someone said that I had to stop the apache module or mysql module, already did it, but no luck... any help with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you are no need to use the port number.

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

I hope this will work. If you are using a Linux version. please check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19127/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-after-installation) thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem using easyphp with php, mysql and apache and solved it by running as administrator

Comment: ok vote me down - fact is I had same error and when I ran easyphp as administrator it solved the problem

Comment: Thank God... I was trying to fix the localhost problem for an hour now - and running the xxamp server as administrator worked for me!!! :)

Comment: @MattGotJava - Hi old question now (even though it got voted down initially - it seems it worked) could you maybe accept the question as correct if you feel it was

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as your local server? Have you restarted the services? Does it say your localhost is running properly?

Comment: I'm following a youtube video and it says that I have to enter my localhost:8080/phpmyadmin into my web browser....Im currently trying it on google chrome... also "restarted the services"? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well usually you need to run a local server. Some IDE's (editors) will have this built in, like netbeans for example. WAMP is another popular one, which runs mysql and phpmyadmin; but WAMP doesn't include an editor, so then you would use something like notepad++.

When you go to http://localhost/ what do you see? If your server software is not running it will probably say "site can not be reached".

I believe you do not have to enter the port if it is the default like 8080... personally I use a different port and have to enter "http://localhost:XXXX/ like you are.

Comment: What is the link to the youtube tutorial you are following?